# Nested grouping of array

Tags: mongodb

There are 3 master collection of category , subcategory and criteria each, i will be building framework with any possible combination of category , subcategory and criteria which will be stored as below-

framework document is added below having list of criteriaconfig  as embedded object which further have single object of category , subcategory and criteria. you can refer criteriaconfig  as link table that u call in mysql.

```
[
  {
    "id": "592bc3059f3ad715002b2331",
    "name": "Framework1",
    "description": "framework 1 for testing",
    "criteriaConfigs": [
      {
        "id": "592bc3059f3ad715002b232f",
        "category": {
          "id": "591c2f5faa187956b2d0fb39",
          "name": "category1",
          "description": "category1",
          "deleted": false,
          "createdDate": 1495019359558
        },
        "subCategory": {
          "id": "591c2f5faa187956b2d0fb83",
          "name": "subCat1",
          "description": "subCat1"
        },
        "criteria": {
          "id": "591c2f5faa187956b2d0fbad",
          "name": "criteria1",
          "measure": "Action"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "592bc3059f3ad715002b232e",
        "category": {
          "id": "591c2f5faa187956b2d0fb37",
          "name": "Process",
          "description": "Enagagement"
        },
        "subCategory": {
          "id": "591c2f5faa187956b2d0fb81",
          "name": "COMM / BRANDING",
          "description": "COMM / BRANDING"
        },
        "criteria": {
          "id": "591c2f5faa187956b2d0fba9",
          "name": "Company representative forgets about customer on hold",
          "measure": ""
        }
      }    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "592bc3059f3ad715002b2332",
    "name": "Framework2",
    "description": "framework 2 for testing",
    "criteriaConfigs": [
      {
        "id": "592bc3059f3ad715002b232f",
        "category": {
          "id": "591c2f5faa187956b2d0fb39",
          "name": "category1",
          "description": "category1"
        },
        "subCategory": {
          "id": "591c2f5faa187956b2d0fb83",
          "name": "subCat1",
          "description": "subCat1"
        },
        "criteria": {
          "id": "591c2f5faa187956b2d0fbad",
          "name": "criteria1",
          "measure": "Action"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

i need a view containing framework  that will contain all list of category and inside category there will be list of added subcategory and inside subcategory will have list of criteria for single framework.

expected result -

```
[
  {
    "id": "f1",
    "name": "Framework1",
    "description": "framework 1 for testing",
    "categories": [
      {
          "id": "c2",
          "name": "category2",
          "description": "category2",
           "subCategories": [
            {
          "id": "sb1",
          "name": "subCat1",
          "description": "subCat1",
          "criterias": [
            {
          "id": "cr1",
          "name": "criteria1",
          "measure": "Action"
            },
            {
          "id": "cr2",
          "name": "criteria2",
          "measure": "Action"
            },
            {
          "id": "cr3",
          "name": "criteria3",
          "measure": "Action"
            }]
            },
            {
          "id": "sb2",
          "name": "subCat2",
          "description": "subCat2",
          "criterias": [
            {
          "id": "cr1",
          "name": "criteria1",
          "measure": "Action"
            },
            {
          "id": "cr4",
          "name": "criteria4",
          "measure": "Action"
            }]
            }]
      },
      {
          "id": "c1",
          "name": "category1",
          "description": "category1",
           "subCategories": [
            {
          "id": "sb3",
          "name": "subCat3",
          "description": "subCat3",
          "criterias": [
            {
          "id": "cr1",
          "name": "criteria1",
          "measure": "Action"
            },
            {
          "id": "cr2",
          "name": "criteria2",
          "measure": "Action"
            }
            ]},
            {
          "id": "sb2",
          "name": "subCat2",
          "description": "subCat2",
          "criterias": [
            {
          "id": "cr1",
          "name": "criteria1",
          "measure": "Action"
            },
            {
          "id": "cr4",
          "name": "criteria4",
          "measure": "Action"
            }]
            }
            ]
      }]
      },
      {
    "id": "f2",
    "name": "Framework2",
    "description": "framework 2 for testing",
    "categories": [
      {
          "id": "c2",
          "name": "category2",
          "description": "category2",
           "subCategories": [
            {
          "id": "sb4",
          "name": "subCat5",
          "description": "subCat5",
          "criterias": [
            {
          "id": "cr1",
          "name": "criteria1",
          "measure": "Action"
            },
            {
          "id": "cr3",
          "name": "criteria3",
          "measure": "Action"
            }]
            },
            {
          "id": "sb2",
          "name": "subCat2",
          "description": "subCat2",
          "criterias": [
            {
          "id": "cr1",
          "name": "criteria1",
          "measure": "Action"
            },
            {
          "id": "cr4",
          "name": "criteria4",
          "measure": "Action"
            }]
            }]
      },
      {
          "id": "c1",
          "name": "category1",
          "description": "category1",
           "subCategories": [
            {
          "id": "sb3",
          "name": "subCat3",
          "description": "subCat3",
          "criterias": [
            {
          "id": "cr1",
          "name": "criteria1",
          "measure": "Action"
            },
            {
          "id": "cr2",
          "name": "criteria2",
          "measure": "Action"
            }
            ]},
            {
          "id": "sb2",
          "name": "subCat2",
          "description": "subCat2",
          "criterias": [
            {
          "id": "cr1",
          "name": "criteria1",
          "measure": "Action"
            },
            {
          "id": "cr4",
          "name": "criteria4",
          "measure": "Action"
            }]
            }
            ]
      }]
      }
      ]
```

Note - Category document doesn't have any reference to subcategory and same way subcategory doesn't have any reference to criteria object currently as they are master data and are generic , framework is created with their combination dynamically.

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking here. Perhaps you should [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44277443/edit) your question and add what sort of output you are expecting. Also note that you are showing only a single document and "grouping" generally implies more than one document. It is also worthwhile to show *what you have tried so far* since you are more likely to get some assistance if it's clear you made an attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: may be now u can relate to it. i actually tried aggreate having group by on framework collection with unwind operation but not of any use

Comment: We can "guess" that you tried. But what we **need** is to see what you are expecting as a result. So two documents in the sample is better, but the "expected output" will go a long way as to making what you want to do clear. So if you show how these two documents ( or another two documents ) are meant to "group", then I'm sure people will get it.

Comment: I have updated expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try to do all the work in the aggregation, you could group first by subcategory, then by category like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$criteriaConfigs"},
    {$project:{ 
               _id:0,
               category:"$criteriaConfigs.category",
               subCategory:"$criteriaConfigs.subCategory",
               criteria:"$criteriaConfigs.criteria"
    }},
    {$group:{
             _id:{"category":"$category","subCategory":"$subCategory"},
             criteria:{$addToSet:"$criteria"}
    }},
    {$group:{
             _id:{"category":"$_id.category"}, 
             subCategories:{$addToSet:{subCategory:"$_id.subCategory",
                                       criteria:"$criteria"}}
    }},
    {$project:{
               _id:0,category:"$_id.category",
               subCategories:"$subCategories"
    }}
])
```

Depending on how you plan to us the return data, it may be more efficient to return each unique combination:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$criteriaConfigs"},
    {$group:{
             _id:{
                  category:"$criteriaConfigs.category.name",
                  subCategory:"$criteriaConfigs.subCategory.name",
                  criteria:"$criteriaConfigs.criteria.name"
                 }
    }},
    {$project:{
               _id:0,
               category:"$_id.category",
               subCategory:"$_id.subCategory",
               criteria:"$_id.criteria"
    }}
])
```

I'm not sure from your question what shape you are expecting the return data to have, so you may need to adjust for that.

Comment: Thanks but this way i am able to achieve that category is bind to what all sub categories and sub category is bind to what all criteria... but i need info about framework having categories then category having subcategory and subcategory having criteria